# How do I group a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have googled and tried various ways to do this (usually around the `itertools.groupby()`), but I'm obviously not thinking about it the right way, so I'd be really glad for some help. I need to merge the hostname key into a list of hostnames where all other keys match.

So I have a list of dicts:

```
MyList = [
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'DEF', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'GHI', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The sky is blue', 'state': 'notsobad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The birds are pretty', 'state': 'prettybad' }
]
```

and I need to merge them based on hostname when the other keys match, i.e:

```
GroupedList = [
    {'hostnames': ['ABC','DEF','GHI'], 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The sky is blue', 'state': 'notsobad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The birds are pretty', 'state': 'prettybad' }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the dicts as a follow-up to `itertools.groupby()`. The following solution leans heavily on the unpacking operator, which isn't always intuitive, to work in a single line, but I'll do my best to explain.

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'DEF', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'GHI', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The sky is blue', 'state': 'notsobad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The birds are pretty', 'state': 'prettybad' }
]

grouped_list = [
    {**lst[0], 'hostname': [d['hostname'] for d in lst]}
    for lst in [
        list(group) for _, group in groupby(my_list, key=lambda d: (d['servicecheck'], d['state']))
    ]
]
# [
#   {'hostname': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad'}, 
#   {'hostname': ['ABC'], 'servicecheck': 'The sky is blue', 'state': 'notsobad'}, 
#   {'hostname': ['ABC'], 'servicecheck': 'The birds are pretty', 'state': 'prettybad'}
# ]
```

First, we use a list comprehension to loop through the groups in `itertools.groupby()`. You can provide a custom key, which I've done, to group adjacent elements by the `'servicecheck'` and `'state'` keys (and if you want to be able to catch and group out-of-order occurrences, you can call `sorted()` on the thing first and use the same key).

Then, we use another list comprehension to convert each of the *iterators* that make up each group from `groupby()`, into *lists*, so we can use them more than once in the expression, which we'll need to do.

Next, for each group, we create a dict. This isn't a dict comprehension - rather, it's an interesting idiom that uses the unpacking operator `**` to convert a dict to another dict (essentially, writing a dict literal but taking the keys and values from an existing dict). So the expression `{**lst[0]}` makes a new dict but copying the keys and values from `lst[0]`. Note that all of the keys and values except `'hostname'` are the same between everything in the group.

We accommodate for that by then *overwriting* the `'hostname'` key in the same literal - here, we just pull all the different hostnames out of the list and stick 'em in a list, which we assign over the original.

So this expression `{**lst[0], 'hostname': [d['hostname'] for d in lst]}` is functionally equivalent to

```
{
    'hostname': lst[0]['hostname'],           # will be overwritten
    'servicecheck': lst[0]['servicecheck'],
    'state': lst[0]['state'],
    'hostname': [d['hostname'] for d in lst]  # overwrites the first one
}
```

We do that for each of the groups to get our answer.

---

(if you want the second and third items in the output to be strings instead of singleton lists, you can replace

```
[d['hostname'] for d in y]
```

with

```
[d['hostname'] for d in y] if len(y) > 1 else y[0]['hostname']
```

)

Comment: This did exactly what I was after, and 30 minutes on google wasnt able to help with. I'll stare at the screen till it becomes more obvious whats happening. What does the underscore in : 'for _, tup in' do? Oh and thanks!

Comment: @DaveM `itertools.groupby()` returns an iterable of 2-tuples - the first element of each is the result of the key function, that's shared by everything in the group; and the second element is the group itself, which is really all we care about. I use `_` as a placeholder variable name to indicate "this variable does not matter and is not used, but needs to be here because the syntax requires it".

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. Thats nice and elegant, taught me about the ** operator too, which I've not come across.

Comment: @DaveM For unpacking operators, [this is a decent tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20the%20unpacking%20operators,only%20be%20used%20on%20dictionaries.). The usual use for them is to either declare a method with an arbitrary number of positional or keyword arguments, or to pass a list/dict to a function as positional/keyword arguments instead of as a list/dict. This is a niche use that doesn't often come up.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList= [
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'DEF', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'GHI', 'servicecheck': 'The roof is on fire', 'state': 'prettybad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The sky is blue', 'state': 'notsobad' },
    {'hostname': 'ABC', 'servicecheck': 'The birds are pretty', 'state': 'prettybad' }
]
visitedIndexes  = {}
myListLen=len(myList)
for i in range(0,myListLen):
    if i in visitedIndexes:
        myList[i]=None
    else:
        visitedIndexes[i]=True
        #process the current index 
        for j in range(i+1,myListLen):
            if myList[i]["servicecheck"] == myList[j]["servicecheck"] and myList[i]["state"]==myList[j]["state"]:
                #group into the i index 
                if  isinstance(myList[i]["hostname"], str): 
                    myList[i]["hostname"]=[ myList[i]["hostname"]]
                myList[i]["hostname"].append(myList[j]["hostname"])
                visitedIndexes[j]=True
myListFinal=[obj  for obj in myList if obj!=None]
print(myListFinal)
```